# Cambiar de color a div con math.random, por medio de funcion?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Me gustaría cambiarle de color al div por medio de la función, la cual ya la tengo con math.random, pero no puedo cambiarlo de color, por que?
y lo otro es, cuando yo precioso el botón encender, el div encenderá con el color amarillo el cual dura 2 segundos y luego se apagara, por el momento no me enciende cando precioso el botón,enciende después y se apaga. como puedo encenderlo y a pagarlo?

```js
var color=false;

function cambiar() {    

     color = !color;    

     document.getElementById("divchangecolor").style.background= color ? "" : "yellow";    

    setTimeout("cambiar()",2000);


}

function myNumber(maxNumber) {

    var random_number = Math.random();
    var random_integer = random_number * maxNumber;
    var my_integer = Math.floor(random_integer);

    return my_integer;
}

var color1=false;
function color(){
    color1 = !color1;
    document.getElementById("divchangecolor").style.background = 'rgb(' + myNumber(255) + ',' + myNumber(255) + ',' + myNumber(255) + ')';
}
```

```html
<div id="divchangecolor" >
  div que cambia de color, se enciende 2 segundos y se apaga.
</div>

<button class="conten" onclick="cambiar()">encender</button>
<button class="color"> cambiar el de color</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primer problema es que no te funciona el cambio de color random por que tienes declarada una variable con el mismo nombre que la función `color`, esto se arregla cambiado el nombre de una de ellas.

Entendiendo tu función `cambiar()` veo que estas haciendo que sea una función pseudo-recursiva infinita, por lo que en vez de encenderse y apagarse estará parpadeando. Ademas de que primero se apaga y después se enciende, que es justo lo contrario a lo que buscas.

Se puede simplificar mucho simplemente cambiando el color a amarillo en el click y volviendo a dejar el "computed style" tras 2 segundos.

```
function cambiar() {      
    document.getElementById("divchangecolor").style.background="yellow";    
    setTimeout(function(){
      document.getElementById("divchangecolor").style.background=""; 
    },2000);
}
```

**Snippet:**

```js
var color=false;

function cambiar() {      
    document.getElementById("divchangecolor").style.background="yellow";    

    setTimeout(function(){
      document.getElementById("divchangecolor").style.background=""; 
    },2000);


}

function myNumber(maxNumber) {

    var random_number = Math.random();
    var random_integer = random_number * maxNumber;
    var my_integer = Math.floor(random_integer);

    return my_integer;
}

var color1=false;
function colorFunc(){
    color1 = !color1;
    document.getElementById("divchangecolor").style.background = 'rgb(' + myNumber(255) + ',' + myNumber(255) + ',' + myNumber(255) + ')';
}
```

```html
<div id="divchangecolor" >
  div que cambia de color, se enciende 2 segundos y se apaga.
</div>

<button class="conten" onclick="cambiar()">encender</button>
<button class="color" onclick="colorFunc()"> cambiar el de color</button>
```

---

Y como posible mejora igual te interesa guardar el color para que cuando se vuelva a encender no se pierda...

**Snippet que guarda el color tras apagar:**

```js
var color=false;
var randomColor="";

function cambiar() {      
    document.getElementById("divchangecolor").style.background="yellow";    

    setTimeout(function(){
      randomColor != "" ? document.getElementById("divchangecolor").style.background =randomColor : document.getElementById("divchangecolor").style.background =""; 
    },2000);


}

function myNumber(maxNumber) {

    var random_number = Math.random();
    var random_integer = random_number * maxNumber;
    var my_integer = Math.floor(random_integer);

    return my_integer;
}

var color1=false;
function colorFunc(){
    color1 = !color1;
    randomColor = "rgb("+myNumber(255)+","+myNumber(255)+","+myNumber(255)+")";
    document.getElementById("divchangecolor").style.background = randomColor;
}
```

```html
<div id="divchangecolor" >
  div que cambia de color, se enciende 2 segundos y se apaga.
</div>

<button class="conten" onclick="cambiar()">encender</button>
<button class="color" onclick="colorFunc()"> cambiar el de color</button>
```

Comment: ha quedado perfecto, creo que a un me falta mucho camino por recorre, muchas gracias por corregir el código, realmente no sabia como hacerlo.